# Unable to connect to websocket - tiledesk/chat21-chat-widget

Tags: angular, websocket, chat

Im trying to integrate tiledesk/chat-21 widget from the source code. Based on this repo: https://github.com/Tiledesk

I have downloaded the:
tiledesk-server
tiledesk-dashboard
chat-21 widget
chat-21-cloud functions.

I have deployed the cloud functions, ran the server and dashboard and created my project. However, when I attach my web widget to a empty html page:

```
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    window.tiledeskSettings=
    {
        projectid: "6571d97415c13c7350b24912"
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
       var w=window; var d=document; var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};  
       i.q=[]; i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);}; w.Tiledesk=i; 
       var js, fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   
       js=d.createElement(s);   
       js.id=id; js.async=true; js.src="http://localhost:4600/launch.js"; 
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document,'script','tiledesk-jssdk'));
 </script>
</head>
```

Im getting this:
[image]

I notice that its trying to connect to this url: ws://0.0.0.0/ng-cli-ws.

I'm not very familiar with the chat-21 widget settings but im wondering where to set the url for the websocket connection?
Why is the connection ws://0.0.0.0/ng-cli-ws? Is this the abstraction that angular does when trying to connect to websocket or is it because there was no specific url set?
I checked my tiledesk-server logs and it doesnt seem to hit it.
However, when i created a simple ws client and specified the correct url it connects no issue so im guessing its some settings I have to set in the tiledesk-widget.